# How to implement Retrofit callback in another class?

Tags: android, retrofit

Right now I am making a retrofit call in one of my fragments

```
private void makeNetworkCall(Comment comment){
        RetrofitInterfaces.IPostNewComment service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterfaces.IPostNewComment.class);
        Call<EventCommentsDao> call = service.listRepos(comment);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EventCommentsDao>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EventCommentsDao> call, Response<EventCommentsDao> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: NewComment: " + response.message());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EventCommentsDao> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failed to post new comment: " + t);
            }
        });

    }
```

```
public interface IPostNewComment{
        @POST("addcomment")
        Call<EventCommentsDao> listRepos(@Body Comment comment);
    }
```

How can I implement the callback methods in another class but still make the network call in the current class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is just like any other variable. You can extract it as a parameter and pass it from another class (if you made the method public / static)

```
private void makeNetworkCall(Comment comment, Callback<EventCommentsDao> cb){
    RetrofitInterfaces.IPostNewComment service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitInterfaces.IPostNewComment.class);
    Call<EventCommentsDao> call = service.listRepos(comment);
    call.enqueue(cb);
}
```